# Why is there a ‘w’ in the word ‘Answer’?

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling, silent-letters

This might sound silly. I understand ‘w’ is silent. But what purpose does ‘w’ serve? Why is it important to have ‘w’ in there? Why not just ‘Anser’ like it’s pronounced?

Comment: just check out the etymology dude, https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/answer

Comment: There has been at least one attempt (Webster, late 1820s) to rationalise English spellings that was accepted in some quarters, but historical aberrations persist from when spellings in England became largely standardised (Johnson, 1750s). The odd aesc (æ) and ethel (œ) that once appeared in fairly common words have been dropped in the last century, and 'AmE' spellings have become invasive in the UK. //// Also, "Why is there a ‘w’ in the word ‘Answer’?" might be valid if accompanied by research, but "[W]hat purpose does ‘w’ serve?" borders on the gripy.

Comment: Because English.

Comment: *Answer* is not pronounced "anser". Even more to the point, it is pronounced twenty different ways around the world. If you use spelling to actually reflect your pronunciation, nobody will understand anything you write. The "w" in *answer* is not silent; all letters in all words are. Spoken language is primary, and was not invented to read aloud glyphs. Much rather, written language was invented to convey the intended meaning through writing rather than sound. Spelling encodes a whole bunch of different things, and pronunciation is only one of them, and not even the most important one.

Comment: @Hot Licks that is dangerously incorrect. It's not because English, it's because every language ever.

Comment: Wai don't we rait evry word tha way we pronauns it?

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul go rait ahed n si hawat wor ksout.

Comment: @RegDwigнt - Consider Spanish, which has "authorities" who link spelling and pronunciation.  When the pronunciation of a word has changed they change the spelling to match.

Answer (score 5):

The w is not the result of purpose but of conventional retention of previous forms. Etymonline.com has “answer” as - Old English andswaru "a response, a reply to a question," from and- "against" (from PIE root *ant- "front, forehead," with derivatives meaning "in front of, before") + -swaru "affirmation," from swerian "to swear" (see swear), suggesting an original sense of "sworn statement rebutting a charge." Meaning "solution of a problem" is from c. 1300.

More generally, the parallels between the written word and the sound of the word are not rigid, or I could have written “konvennshunal ritennshun”; but I don’t, because I adhere to convention.

Comment: Please don't do OP's required research for them.

Comment: I believed that we are encouraged to give sources where appropriate. I have done so. OP (I assume you mean the person asking the question) is not “required” to do any research; OP merely asked for an answer; I have given it.

Comment: Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. (ELU policy, not my words.) 'The Online Etymology Dictionary' is listed as one such reference.

Comment: Fair enough, thank you. But etymology does not answer the question as posed. My answer rests on the general notion of conventional retention of form, not on the specifics of the etymology.

Comment: But general comments of the form 'Some changes take place, while other ones that might be expected for the sake of harmonisation don't' is either obvious enough to be over-simplistic, or too broad-brush. Note that others choose to confine answering to 'comments' here.